# CouchDB: bulk update best practices

Tags: couchdb, handler, bulk

My use case: i would set a flag ("read" or "unread") in a group of documents with only one request.
My first idea was to send a list of ids using an _update handler but reading docs it seem to work only on one document.
I'm wrong? How to solve this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

Currently (CouchDB 1.1.0 and to my knowledge the next release, 1.2 also), the only way to modify documents *in bulk* is to send the literal documents themselves to CouchDB using the [CouchDB bulk document API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API).

In my experience, in practice, this is not a major problem because bulk operations tend to be done with offline tools or else with AJAX operations where there is no noticeable impact to the user experience.